# Считывание файла со второй строки

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как считать файл в формате csv со второй строки?

Comment: Пропустить первую строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));            
boolean firstLine = true;               
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (firstLine) {
            firstLine = false;
            continue;
        } 
    list.add(line);              
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    reader.readLine();
    String secondString = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(secondString);

}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]